# Can someone explain me the following code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't understand what this code is trying to do

```
export type ReactNode =
  | React$Element<any>
  | ReactPortal
  | ReactText
  | ReactFragment
  | ReactProvider<any>
  | ReactConsumer<any>;
```

Comment: This is just a type definition of a `ReactNode` element.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

Answer (score 0):

It's defining the type `ReactNode` as a union of all the listed types. You can read about union types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)

Comment: so react is written in typescript?

Comment: Well, I don't know where you got the code from. I don't use React myself, but that looks like typescript code to me. Is this from the official React repository, or is it from a typescript wrapper?

Comment: React repository

Comment: React seems to be written completely in pure javascript, so I doubt it's in the react repository. Did you find this snippet in a file from a npm/node package you have installed locally or did you find it online? If you have it locally, what's the name of that file? If you found it online, can you provide a link?

Comment: @peter if you think this answered your question, please upvote and mark as solved. Thank you

Comment: the code is in ReactTypes.js, you can find it in react repo

Comment: Okay, so I [found it](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/shared/ReactTypes.js). Looks like they use something called flow (thus the `@flow` comment in the beginning), which seems to have similar type concepts as typescript ([including union types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-union-type-syntax)).